# Use Range for a whole column instead of one cell

Tags: vba, excel

What I currently have:

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsEmpty(Range("G15").Value) = True Then
        If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G15")) Is Nothing Then
                Range("G15").Value = Date
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I've created this for the following reason:
I want to click on a cell on which it's automatically puts in the date of today. Now, if the cell already contains text (doesn't matter what), it doesn't have overrule that input.

What I created works perfectly.. for **one** cell. I want it to work for the whole column (in this case, the "G" column).

I tried using Range("G1:G1000"), but that didn't work. I've tried using a tutorial which explains how to use multiple ranges (http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/05/macros-in-excel-selecting-multiple.html) but that didn't work out either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below, this works if you select the row in G that you want date added to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsEmpty(Range("G" & Target.Row).Value) = True Then
        If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G" & Target.Row)) Is Nothing Then
                Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = Date
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. 99moorem was the one I needed. Thanks for the fast responses.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range("G15").EntireColumn
```

Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you might have some non-empty cells in the range, but want to fill all the empty ones, you would need:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillEmptyWithDates()

Dim Cell1 As Range
Dim Range1 As Range

Set Range1 = ActiveWorksheet.Columns(7)
For Each Cell1 in Range1
    If IsEmpty(Cell1.Value) = True Then
        Cell1.Value = Date
    End If
Next Cell1

End Sub
```

I changed your code a little bit because it seemed convoluted for what you seem to be trying to accomplish: fill all empty cells in G with the current date.

This macro no longer triggers every time you select a new cell. You would go to the macros menu, select it, and push the Run button.